# Bootstrap Gap Between Columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap on my current project, it's working fine but only one glitch:

I have 3 `col-sm-6` next to each other, when the second `col-sm-6` is longer than the first, third `col-sm-6` moves to left and a gap appears between first and third one.

I have 2 points to ask about:

- Is it possible / how to remove that gap.
- Is it possible / how to fix the third `.col-sm-6 .tasks-panel` to left.

Here is 2 images demonstrate what problem I have:

- Second `col-sm-6` is short:
  [image: Status 1]
- Second `col-sm-6` is longer than the first:
  [image: Status 2]
  My html structure goes like this:

  ```
        <h4><span data-head-year></span> <span data-head-month></span></h4>
        <a class="pull-right" id="today"><div class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:3px">Today</div></a>
      </div>
      <hr style="margin: 20px 0"/>
      <div class="day-headers">
        <div class="day header">Mon</div>
        <div class="day header">Tue</div>
        <div class="day header">Wed</div>
        <div class="day header">Thu</div>
        <div class="day header">Fri</div>
        <div class="day header">Sat</div>
        <div class="day header">Sun</div>
      </div>
      <div class="days" data-group="days">
        <!-- the place where days will be generated -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Responsive calendar - END -->
  </div>
  ```

  Outlets to visit

  ```
      <div class="template outlet-wrapper" style="display: none">
        <div class="outlet-header">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h4 class="outlet-name"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
            <h5 class="tools" style="display: none">
              <i class="icon-repeat repeat"></i>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove"></span>
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        <div class="outlet-body"> 
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            Time to reach: <spane class="time-to-reach"></spane>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            Time to leave: <span class="time-to-leave"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="add-outlet"> Add Visit </button>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

  Tasks List

  ```
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
  </div>
  ```

Sorry for bad format, I don't know why stackoverflow editor breaks my html code; I have tried (Ctrl + K, `<pre><code>`) but none of them worked !

If you're interested in seeing my code properly, please show my post in editor.

Thanks in advanced.

### Update:

A Codepen is available [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nyvHL), press add visit to see what happens if second column is long.

Comment: Thats probably **not possible** because Bootstrap is working with rows. One row always has the height of the longest element. Obviously the 3rd element is somehow being put into the next row.

Comment: Certainly the third `col-sm-6` will be in next row, because bootstrap grid system consists by 12  columns by default, so in every row will be two columns, thats not my question neither problem.

I want to know if there is a way to stick the third `col-sm-6` always to left and somehow remove that gap.

Comment: Could you set up a quick pen if possible? You can add bootstrap easily using the css settings just type 'boot' and it'll let you add bootstrap. http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: @Leth0_ Or just use bootply.com

Comment: @DavidG Thanks! I never knew that.

Comment: @Leth0_ Or even jsFiddle.net if you add the libraries manually :)

Comment: ...if the structure stays as it is, then you could use float:right for the second col-sm-6 element...

Comment: @Leth0_ Thanks for your mention, I chose codepen.io over bootply.com because I found It easier to add external resources there, also it's more eloquent.

Comment: @Leth0_ this codepen.io is great :),I just saw [full page](http://codepen.io/MWalid/full/AFklh) mode it's awesome !!

Comment: Ok, so you don't want the task list to be pushed to the left?

Comment: Actually I want it to be always sticked to the left without gap.

Comment: Have you tried to apply "pull-right" the the "col-sm-6" container of "panel panel-primary outlets-panel"? Forked Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxdDj - Now you need to fix the above space of the "tasks list" container, but that should be trivial.

Comment: Thanks @Bonatoc That solved it!
you may add your comment as answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to apply "pull-right" to the "col-sm-6" container of "panel panel-primary outlets-panel"?

```
<div class="col-sm-6 pull-right">
<div class="panel panel-primary outlets-panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    ...
```

[Forked Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxdDj)

You'll still have to fix the above space of the "tasks list" container, but that should be trivial.

Comment: this will work only in bigger than `sm` screens, try to resize the window until it will be smaller than `sm` screen and see the result.

Comment: That's what xs classes are for. Sure you don't expect xs screens to have 6 + 6... My suggestion is to add col-xs-12 to all main blocks. Codepen updated.

Comment: Codepen updated. The only remaining problem is the hierarchy of the panels. If you need the "Outlets" before the "Tasks", you have to move the div in first position, but that makes "Calendar" second in xs screens. But that is the problem of having all of them in one single row.

Comment: The hierarchy is fine in my local copy and my pen, only yours is wrong:), there is no need to move anything, please check [my pen](http://codepen.io/MWalid/full/AFklh), Thanks again :)