# Bootstrap white break in grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap panel gives a white break when I add content to my right sidebar.
I tried to change the col-mds and adding a clearfix, but that didn't worked.

Picture: https://i.snag.gy/54SNqw.jpg

Code:

```css
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
.custom-header-panel {
  background-color: #004b8e !important;
  border-color: #004b8e !important;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading custom-header-panel">
        <h3 class="panel-title roboto">Profile info</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading custom-header-panel">
        <h3 class="panel-title roboto">Profile info</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        This doesn't work. tste
        <br>test
        <br>test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading custom-header-panel">
        <h3 class="panel-title roboto">Profile info</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading custom-header-panel">
        <h3 class="panel-title roboto">Profile info</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea's to fix this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "white break". Do you mean the spacing (padding) between the columns? http://www.codeply.com/go/Aal8awp4pz

Comment: Are you talking about the gap caused because the sidebar is taller than the first panel? If so this question has been answered on SO before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572753/bootstrap-3-fluid-grid-layout-issues/19573033 Also, you don't need to keep using a new `row` tag.

Comment: I am talking about that white block part between the first panel and the second panel: https://i.snag.gy/4xiu5p.jpg

Comment: It's because of the height of the columns and has aleady been answered on SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718039/bootstrap-gap-between-columns, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572753/bootstrap-3-fluid-grid-layout-issues/19573033 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196082/bootstrap-how-to-stack-divs-of-different-heights Your options are to make panels the same hieght, use CSS3 columns or masonry plugin.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add outer div - `container-fluid`, after this you need add div with class `row` which is wrapping `panel`.

Breaks appear because all classes `col-*-*` (as well as `container-fluid`) have default left and right paddings equal **15px**. Class `row` compensates these paddings with its negative left and right margins equal **-15px**.

Actually, you can just add class `row` to the `<div class="panel">`, but it's not very right solution.

```css
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
.custom-header-panel {
  background-color: #004b8e !important;
  border-color: #004b8e !important;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading custom-header-panel">
        <h3 class="panel-title roboto">Profile info</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading custom-header-panel">
        <h3 class="panel-title roboto">Profile info</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        This doesn't work. tste
        <br>test
        <br>test
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading custom-header-panel">
        <h3 class="panel-title roboto">Profile info</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-heading custom-header-panel">
        <h3 class="panel-title roboto">Profile info</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```